# AutoFocus is not working on Galaxy S9 and S9+ with Zxing library

Tags: android, zxing, galaxy

・symptom
The app is using zxing 1.9 for QR code reading.
It works well in almost android devices, but dose not work well in Galaxy S9 and S9+ devices.
It seems like auto focus is not working.
Upto Galaxy version 8, no problem.

・environment
Android : 5 to 8.0
Kernel ver : 4.9.65-144892203
zxing : 1.9 version
Device : Galaxy S9 , Galaxy S9+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the issue with following code.
Working well with Galaxy S8, S8+, S9, S9+.

```
private val autoFocusExecutor = ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1)

fun startCamera() {
if (camera == null) {
    camera = Camera.open()
    if (camera == null) {
        showCameraErrorMsg()
    } else {
        preview.camera = camera
        capturereceipt_textview_cameraerrormsg.visibility = View.GONE
        capturereceipt_framelayout_viewfinder.visibility = View.VISIBLE

        autoFocusExecutor.schedule(Sc{
            val params: Camera.Parameters = camera!!.parameters
            if (params.getSupportedFocusModes()
                    .contains(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE)) {
                //TODO: Auto focus not working
                params.focusMode = Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE
            }
            camera?.parameters = params
        }, 1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    }
}}
```